# How to make a mail as read after fetch from the mail box using imap in php

Tags: php, email, imap, fetch

How to make a mail as read after fetch from the mail box using imap in php.

I fetch emails from mailbox using pop3 and imap. It fetched from mailbox and displayed.
when i trying to set flag mail as Seen it's not working.
It always in the status of "Unread".
I don't know how to fix it.

My code like,

```
$con = imap_open("{mydomain.com:143/pop3/tls/novalidate-cert}INBOX", $user, $pass);

$MC = imap_check($con); 

$range = "1:".$MC->Nmsgs; 

$response = imap_fetch_overview($con,$range); 

foreach ($response as $msg) {

        $msgno = $msg->msgno;

        $headerinfo=imap_headerinfo($con, $msgno);

        $h = get_object_vars($headerinfo);

        print_r($h);

        $status = imap_setflag_full($con, "2,5", "\\Seen \\Flagged");
}
imap_close($con);
```

Comment: Why do you use "2,5" instead of $msgno ? Anyway, you should use a library like https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap . Would be a lot easier.

Comment: first am using the $msgno to set the flag. that's not working so i tried something like 2,5.